# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error depending on symbol names used - Clojure

Tags: linux, terminal, clojure, boot-clj

I am a beginner at Clojure. I am performing one operation twice, but with changed symbols `lang` against `language`

One case it is working well, another is throwing an error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'my-method' for dispatch value: null`

I am not sure if it is caused by an Clojure syntax or there is something wrong in my linux configuration. I have Debian Stretch and boot.clj.

The error happens in the terminal. Here you are the both peaces of code an the error:

```
s@lokal:~$ boot repl
nREPL server started on port 36091 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:36091
java.lang.Exception: No namespace: reply.eval-modes.nrepl found
REPL-y 0.4.1, nREPL 0.4.4
Clojure 1.8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13
        Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
    Commands: (user/help)
        Docs: (doc function-name-here)
              (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
Find by Name: (find-name "part-of-name-here")
      Source: (source function-name-here)
     Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Examples from clojuredocs.org: [clojuredocs or cdoc]
              (user/clojuredocs name-here)
              (user/clojuredocs "ns-here" "name-here")
boot.user=> (do
       #_=> (defmulti my-method (fn[x] (x "lang")))
       #_=> (defmethod my-method "English" [params] "Hello!")
       #_=> (def english-map {"id" "1", "lang" "English"})
       #_=>     (my-method english-map)
       #_=> )
"Hello!"
boot.user=> 

boot.user=> (do
       #_=> (defmulti my-method (fn[x] (x "language")))
       #_=> (defmethod my-method "English" [params] "Hello!")
       #_=> (def english-map {"id" "1", "language" "English"})
       #_=>     (my-method english-map)
       #_=> )

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'my-method' for dispatch value: null
boot.user=>
```

I must add that before it worked with `language` but not with `lang`. It also turned to work or did not when I was changing a `my-method` symbol name with `mymetho-d` or `greeting`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defmulti` defines a var, and subsequent calls to `defmulti` with the same name do nothing, so your second `defmulti` call is ineffective and the original dispatch function remains. There's `remove-method` and `remove-all-methods` for removing `defmethod` definitions, but to remove a `defmulti` definition (without restarting REPL) you can use `alter-var-root` to set the var to nil:

```
(defmulti my-method (fn [x] (x "lang")))
(defmethod my-method "English" [params] "Hello!")
(def english-map {"id" "1", "lang" "English"})
(my-method english-map)
=> "Hello!"

(alter-var-root #'my-method (constantly nil)) ;; set my-method var to nil

(def english-map {"id" "1", "language" "English"})
(defmulti my-method (fn [x] (x "language")))
(defmethod my-method "English" [params] "Hello!")
(my-method english-map)
=> "Hello!"
```

You can use `ns-unmap` to similar effect:

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'my-method)
```